# How can I get my browser to remember a password it doesn't offer to remember?

Tags: internet, web-browser, authentication

In my university internet authentication is required. When i use Macbook to connect to internet the **password popup window** will be appear. On this window I cannot set it to remember my ID/Password. Every times I want to use internet I have to login it manually.

I've tried to setup my Chrome, Safari to remember my authentication ID/Password but I don't know exactly where the popup window comes from.

How can I store my password so I don't have to enter it every time?

[image]

Comment: The KeyChain could be used for this or you could delete your browser cache, cookies and every password setting. It will prompt you again to save the password in the browser.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the password popup?

Comment: @patrix i added it already.

Comment: Thanks. Certificates are not passwords (and Keychain won't help here), I've adapted your question accordingly. Feel free to fix any errors I may have introduced during the edit.

Comment: Sorry @patrix In actually, after i click continue the internet authentication page will come. my problem is i cannot set this popup to remember my internet ID/password i have to type ID/password every times. but for chrome and safari are no problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is here: Is it the dialog you show in the screenshot or is it something which happens after you clicked "continue"? In the second case, can you please add some details/screenshot as well?

Comment: @patrix I changed the screenshot already. my question is so simple "How to set this dialog to remember my ID/Password?"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on HOW they ask for the password some browsers dont recognize the request. However it is also possible that this website has a little bit of code in it to tell the browser to NOT remember the password. Banks often do this and I gather it is pretty trivial to turn off "remember passwords" on a web page.

I use a little javascript that will (sometimes) bypass this:

- Create a bookmark of ANY page (it doesnt matter which page as we will be replacing the URL and name)
- Go into Show All Bookmarks and select the bookmark you just made.
- In the Address field (where the URL is) click and remove ALL of the url and replace it with this:

  ```
  javascript:(function(){var%20ca,cea,cs,df,dfe,i,j,x,y;function%20n(i,what){return%20i+%22%20%22+what+((i==1)?%22%22:%22s%22)}ca=cea=cs=0;df=document.forms;for(i=0;i%3Cdf.length;++i){x=df[i];dfe=x.elements;if(x.onsubmit){x.onsubmit=%22%22;++cs;}if(x.attributes[%22autocomplete%22]){x.attributes[%22autocomplete%22].value=%22on%22;++ca;}for(j=0;j%3Cdfe.length;++j){y=dfe[j];if(y.attributes[%22autocomplete%22]){y.attributes[%22autocomplete%22].value=%22on%22;++cea;}}}alert(%22Removed%20autocomplete=off%20from%20%22+n(ca,%22form%22)+%22%20and%20from%20%22+n(cea,%22form%20element%22)+%22,%20and%20removed%20onsubmit%20from%20%22+n(cs,%22form%22)+%22.%20After%20you%20type%20your%20password%20and%20submit%20the%20form,%20the%20browser%20will%20offer%20to%20remember%20your%20password.%22)})();
  ```
- Now edit the NAME of the password and change it to something like "Remember Password."

I put this bookmark in the bookmark bar, so you can drag it there if you like.

Now when yo go to a page that won't remember your password, click that bookmark and then enter your username and password. If Safari then asks if you want to remember the password: SUCCESS!

If not then I don't have a solution for you. However I use 1Password to fill in most password, but that ain't free...

Comment: gosh ......could you format that code please

Comment: Good answer but not what was asked. The OP is not on Internet, it is trying to connect to it via router and needs to autofill the router login credentials, not a web page.

Comment: Hard to tell but it looks like the router log in page may be a browser window. If not then my only answer is something like using 1Password...

Comment: it is a javascript src="/md5.js" in a html page send by router.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the image you are looking at is not from any browser like Safari or Chrome.

It is generated by the Router you are tying to connect to.

That is why the browsers wont help you if you try to use saved passwords.

However, once connected and on the Internet, if you loose that connection for some reason then the browser will help you reconnecting and automatically supply the saved password. So save it in Browser and on you key cahin.

You question is how to automatically provide a login to the Routers pop up login window.

There is a problem.

Since that pop up is not associated with any programs on you computer they can not do the auto-fill.

But there is a very simple solution.

Do as usual, when connecting.

Now the surprise: **IGNORE** the pop up window!!

Yes you can close that popup window.

Go to your browser where you have saved the login and call that website from your bookmarks.

In your case it should have this

> `https://1.1.1.1/fs/customwebauth/login`

Surprise, now the browser will login and fill out the password for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to say for sure without being able to investigate the page in question. However, this solution has a high probability of being exactly what you are looking for.

Turn on this experimental feature in Google chrome by copying this into the address field, pressing enter, and clicking Enable. A restart of Chrome will be required.

```
chrome://flags/#ignore-autocomplete-off-autofill
```